# How do you run a single OCaml inline test with dune?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm trying to run a single inline test in OCaml, in a dune project. The only command I have is `dune test` which runs all the tests. I can't seem to find the command to run a single test.

Comment: Does [this](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests.html#running-a-single-test) help?

Comment: no this seems to be for binary tests, not inline test, I'll rephrase my question

Comment: created an issue here as well: https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_inline_test/issues/34